# How to handle javascript Promises in iOS JavaScriptCore

Tags: ios, swift, javascriptcore

Is it possible to handle the javascript promises in JSContext in iOS?

I have a running application which uses the iOS JavaScriptCore in swift. All calls toward javascript is working as long as javascript not running Promises. Once the javascript function uses Promises, the call to swift never resolve or rejecte, it will only returns, which contains a javascript promise.

It seems that Promises in javascript endup in differen thread than main thread.

How this should be handled in iOS and JavaScriptCore.
I'm using Xcode 8 and swift 3.0

Thanks Morteza

Answer (score 0):

There was No problem with JavaScriptCore and Promises from javascript. I had a Error in my chain of Promises, which caused the resolve never reached in the javascipt.